# Four Directions #14 - Where and what am I?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge, geography

> To my North is a place that means Warrior King
>
> To my East is a whole town made of books.
>
> To my South there's a very cold airfield for bridge dwellers.
>
> To my West lies the mouth of a jungle snake.

Where am I?

**HINT 1**

> Two of the clues refer to places a lot further away than the other two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

> Whatever is at Latitude 0, Longitude 0. Not sure if there's another name for it.

To my North is a place that means Warrior King

> Ghana. The etymology of the word Ghana means "Warrior King," and 0 degrees Longitude passes through

To my East is a whole town made of books.

> Libreville, very close to the equator on the West coast of Africa

To my South there's a very cold airfield for bridge dwellers.

> One of the far away places, Troll Airfield on Antarctica, which is close enough to the Prime Meridian.

To my West lies the mouth of a jungle snake.

> The other far away place, referring to the mouth of the Amazon River. It meets the Atlantic close to the equator.

Comment: I believe the term you're looking for is rot13[Thys bs Thvarn] :)

Comment: (0,0) is correct, also known as rot13(Ahyy vfynaq) :D